# distributing java jar lib to multiple destinations on clean-build in NetBeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a simple POJO library (build using NetBeans 7.1) and couple of projects that will depend on it (one Grails, one Griffon, maybe Android).

When running 'Clean and Build Project' in NB, what's the easiest way to push the generated .jar to those projects depending on it?

Or should I be thinking about 'pulling' the jar lib when projects depending on it get build? I'm using IntelliJ for the 'consumer' projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your POJO library and other projects maven projects and add it as a dependency, so it will be included as a jar automatically.